# How to genarate the list of all parameters in helm chart template?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Like [nginx chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/nginx), is there a way to quickly generate a list of all parameters?

Comment: If you want to create a list to be used in a helm template, you can use the range function built within helm to loop through values. If you want to use it in a MD file like in the nginx repo, you may have to use a yaml parser to loop over the values and populate them in the desired format. However this would have to run as a part of your parent project's build.

Answer (score 1):

`helm show values nginx bitnami/nginx`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a **dry-run** output with `--dry-run` flag in `helm install` command. This can be outputted to a file with `>`.

e.g.

```bash
helm template <name> <chart> --dry-run -f <optionally-a-file> > parameter-list.yaml
```

These parameters can also be converted to a format that is easier to handle with  `yq` command's `-o=props`.

[YQ command](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/)